# Error writing 3000+ pdf files in one txt file with python 3

Tags: python, text, pypdf

I am trying to extract text from 3000+ PDFs in one txt file (while I had to remove headers from each page):

```
for x in range(len(files)-len(files)+15):
    pdfFileObj=open(files[x],'rb')
    pdfReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    for pageNum in range(1,pdfReader.numPages):
        pageObj=pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
        content=pageObj.extractText()
        removeIndex = content.find('information.') + len('information.')
        newContent=content[removeIndex:]
        file.write(newContent)
file.close()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufb02' in position 5217: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Where is the variable `file` initialized ? Also print the error instead of printing "oops" refer https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: Your except block is essentially silencing any useful error information from ever being shown.  Remove it, run your code, then tell us what errors actually occur.

Comment: @SaicharanSM the variable file is initialized before the loop begins: file=open('allText.txt', 'w')

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your title. (A dirty fix would be to `contents.replace('\ufb02', 'fl')` - the better fix is to use an encoding that supports this character).

Comment: Could you try to open your output file using [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead of the `open()` you're using now, passing appropriate encoding information to the function (btw, have a look at the linked documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to check the encoding of each PDF so I just used replace(). Below is the working code:

```
for x in range(len(files)):
    pdfFileObj=open(os.path.join(filepath,files[x]),'rb')
    for pageNum in range(1,pdfReader.numPages):
        pageObj=pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
        content=pageObj.extractText()
        removeIndex = content.find('information.') + len('information.')
        newContent=content[removeIndex:]
        newContent=newContent.replace('\n',' ')
        newContent=newContent.replace('\ufb02','FL')
        file.write(str(newContent.encode('utf-8')))
file.close()
```